# How to replace duplicated multi-line groups, e.g. from git & diff3

Tags: grep, regular-expression, git, pcregrep

I'm rebasing legacy code, and finding lots of conflicts caused by scripts -- usually code formatters. The changes are simple and predictable, so I can trivially re-run the script to apply the changes to the code -- which usually leaves me with three identical "snippets" surrounded by git's diff markers.

How can I write a script to find three matching snippets, with their diff markers, and convert them to a single snippet?

Example:

`git rebase` produces this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    ACA
    BCB
||||||| parent of 0cfd85b8e3... Beautify.
    AAA
    BBB
=======
    AAC
    BBC
>>>>>>> 0cfd85b8e3... Beautify.
```

Re-running the formatter gives this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    ACC
    BCC
||||||| parent of 0cfd85b8e3... Beautify.
    ACC
    BCC
=======
    ACC
    BCC
>>>>>>> 0cfd85b8e3... Beautify.
```

which I would like to convert to this:

```
    ACC
    BCC
```

I've tried many, many things including grep (it struggles with new-lines) and pcregrep (I struggle with back-references/capture-groups). Any ideas?

Comment: Something like `perl -0777 -pe 's/^<<<<<<< HEAD\n(.*?\n)\Q|||||||\E parent of \N+\n\1=======\n\1>>>>>>> \N+\n/\1/sm'` ? I'm not really sure of your question.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, a stateful Awk program can be quite clear:

```
awk '/^<<<<<<</ { state = 1; next }
     /^=======/ { state = 2; next }
     /^>>>>>>>/ { state = 0; next }
     state == 0 || state == 2' data
foo
prolog
    AAC
    BBC
epilog
bar
```

Where `data` contains:

```
foo
prolog
<<<<<<< HEAD
    ACA
    BCB
||||||| parent of 0cfd85b8e3... Beautify.
    AAA
    BBB
=======
    AAC
    BBC
>>>>>>> 0cfd85b8e3... Beautify.
epilog
bar
```

Initially we are in state 0, because `state == 0` is true if `state` is not yet initialized. We switch to state 1 upon seeing `<<<<<<` and to state 2 upon seeing `=======` and then back to state 0 when we see the end marker `>>>>>>>`. Very simple.

We print lines only if we are in the initial state 0 (outside of any conflict marker) or in state 2 (last part of conflict marker).

The `next` commands in all the cases ensure that we have no fall-through behavior. Only the last case prints anything so we know that the first three cases do nothing but recognize conflict markers and change states, without printing anything. Thus conflict markers are not printed, regardless of what state we are in; we know that in state 2 and in the return to state 0, we will not accidentally print the `=======` or `>>>>>>>` line.

The `next` is not strictly necessary in the first action, because it shifts to the non-printing state 1, but including it is nice for consistency. Also, efficiency: the conflict markers are mutually exclusive; why test for `=======` if you have detected `<<<<<<<`.

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp's `awk` macro can solve this without state variables, because it has more powerful range expressions than conventional Awk:

- range expressions can combine with other expressions. For instance, a range expression can be the start or end of another range;
- range expressions can be used anywhere in the `awk` macro, not just as main clause conditons; and
- range expressions come in [nine different flavors](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-00BEA6DF) for excluding records at the start and end, or extending the range to include more records.

Using the same `data` file as the Awk answer:

```
$ txr awk.tl data
foo
prolog
    AAC
    BBC
epilog
bar
```

Code in `awk.tl`:

```
(awk
  (:let (beg (f^ #/<<<<<<</))
        (mid (f^ #/=======/))
        (end (f^ #/>>>>>>>/)))
  ((-rng- mid end))            ; print lines between ===...>>>, exclusive
  ((not (rng beg end))))       ; print lines outside <<<...>>>
```

Breakdown:

First there is a [`(:let ...)`](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-012F3A2C) clause which binds some lexical variables over the scope of the `awk` form. We introduce the variables `beg`, `mid` and `end`, whose values are one-argument anonymous functions. For instance [`(f^ /abc/)`](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-000B5ACD) yields a function which takes a string, and matches the regular expression `abc`, anchored to the start of that string. We are defining functions for matching the start, middle and end of the diff3 conflict marker.

After the `:let`, we have two `(condition action)` clauses. Neither clause has an `action`, so the default action is to print. This is a form of Awk, so same rules apply.

The range `(-rng- mid end)` matches the records from the `mid` marker to the `end`. The `-rng-` variant yields true only for the interior records of the range; it yields false for the first and last record. This is exactly what we want: we want to print all lines between `======` and `>>>>>>>`, but not including those lines. Awk has no such feature to exclude endpoints from the range.

The second rule's condition is `(not (rng beg end))`.  This condition yields true for records which are not within the `beg` to `end` range; i.e., not within a diff3 conflict annotation. We want to print all those. Awk also doesn't have such a feature: a range expression cannot be combined with any other operator such as `!` negation.

Because of the range features in TXR Lisp's `awk`, no state variables are required in this solution, and no rule has to explicitly branch out of the implicit loop to proceed to the next record.